# Validation rules Account: Changing owner limitation

Tags: validation, account, ownership

I am trying to create a validation rule for Account. I want to limit the capability of the user to transfer the accounts (or changing de ownerID of the Account) . I only want them to be able to transfer Accounts to users that have the same role.

I am not being able to create the validation rule, this is sample of what I did but it is not working.

```
AND(
   ISCHANGED( OwnerId ),
   VLOOKUP($User.UserRole.name,$User.Id,PRIORVALUE(OwnerID)) = $UserRole.name
)
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a formula field on the object that holds the `Owner.UserRole.Name` then use that in your validation rule like:

```
AND(
   ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
   PRIORVALUE(Owner_Role__c) <> Owner.UserRole.Name
)
```

Which would only allow users to change the owner if the existing owner has the same Role as the new owner.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jenny. I have tried to use your validation rules but I have the following error.   Error: Field Owner_Role__c does not exist. Check spelling. Any ideas of what is wrong?

Comment: @Dr.Xavier that was the name of the formula field I created first before creating the validation rule. Did you create a formula field resulting in Text and Owner.UserRole.Name as the formula? Whatever the api name is for that field is what should be set in the PriorValue function.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I made it work. 


AND(
   ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
   PRIORVALUE(  Onwer_Role__c  ) <> Owner.UserRole.Name
)

Comment: @Dr.Xavier Updated the answer, I misunderstood the initial question but glad you got it working!